# How Can I Fix this Array with Object Properties

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8

In trying to debug a JavaScript file in IE8, I got an "Expected identifier, string or number." I thought it might be an extra comma or that I need to put my object properties in quotes (I tried putting them in both double in single quotes), but I still get the "Expected identifier, string or number" error:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.confirm', $.mage.modal, {
        options: {
            modalClass: 'confirm',
            title: '',
            focus: '.action-accept',
            actions: {

                /**
                 * Callback always - called on all actions.
                 */
                always: function () {},

                /**
                 * Callback confirm.
                 */
                confirm: function () {},

                /**
                 * Callback cancel.
                 */
                cancel: function () {}
            },
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Cancel'),
                class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',

                /**
                 * Click handler.
                 */
                click: function (event) {
                    this.closeModal(event);
                }
            }, {
                text: $.mage.__('OK'),
                class: 'action-primary action-accept',

                /**
                 * Click handler.
                 */
                click: function (event) {
                    this.closeModal(event, true);
                }
            }]
        },

        /**
         * Create widget.
         */
        _create: function () {
            this._super();
            this.modal.find(this.options.modalCloseBtn).off().on('click', _.bind(this.closeModal, this));
            this.openModal();
        },

        /**
         * Remove modal window.
         */
        _remove: function () {
            this.modal.remove();
        },

        /**
         * Open modal window.
         */
        openModal: function () {
            return this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Close modal window.
         */
        closeModal: function (event, result) {
            result = result || false;

            if (result) {
                this.options.actions.confirm(event);
            } else {
                this.options.actions.cancel(event);
            }
            this.options.actions.always(event);
            this.element.bind('confirmclosed', _.bind(this._remove, this));

            return this._super();
        }
    });

    return function (config) {
        return $('<div></div>').html(config.content).confirm(config);
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you show your Error in Console?

Comment: On which line do you get that error?

Comment: Before your edited your question the `class` word was not wrapped with single-quote. Is this the case?

Comment: Can you post the whole file, please? `buttons:` appears to be a property of something larger, which might as well contribute to the issue.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, here is the whole file.

Comment: Works fine on other browsers?

Comment: Yes, works fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: Can you show the console or show the error (which line)?

Comment: @GTSJoe did you try to change `class` to `'class'`?